# Origin of the family name affix "tom"

Tags: etymology, names

During my mathematics research, I've come across the mathematician [Tammo tom Dieck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tammo_tom_Dieck). I have never come across the family name affix "tom", neither Wiktionary nor light googling give me anything conclusive, and it is also not listed on [Wikipedia's list of family affixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_family_name_affixes). Is anyone familiar with this?

Comment: Interesting! Do you know the names of his parents? Apparently he was born in Sao Paolo, https://portal.dnb.de/opac.htm?method=simpleSearch&cqlMode=true&query=idn%3D124473091 and his family name is sometimes written as Tom-Dieck

Comment: The names of his parents are not given, but his (German) wiki page identifies a bunch of different relatives, which all seem to come from Germany.
I have also now come across a whole page on the German wikipedia page designated to the last name "tom Dieck": https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Dieck In particular, it claims that the name is related to the German "zum Teich", or "to the pond". No particular sources for that claim, however, but very interesting.

Comment: Careful. Personal nomenclature and kinship designations are a black hole; every name has a voluminous history.

Comment: I see, now it makes sense, Low German tom Diek = High German zum Teich, https://www.niederdeutsche-literatur.de/dwn/dwn_he_alles.php?W_ID=140&ONL=8 and https://www.niederdeutsche-literatur.de/dwn/dwn_he_alles.php?W_ID=1063&ONL=8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dutch *tom* is clearly cognate to High German *zum* which is a contraction of *zu dem* "to the". The German preposition *zu* can be used both in a static sense ("at") and in a directional sense ("to"). In German nobility families, sometimes a distinction was maintained between *von* "from" some place and *zu* "at" some place, and sometimes even *von und zu* "from and at" some place (usually a castle or a fortified town). The *zu* indicates that a family was still living at the eponymous place at the time when the name was fixed.

Note: The static sense of *zu* is somewhat archaic in Modern High German, but still existent, e.g., in *Universität zu Köln* (official name of the Cologne university).

Comment: It’s also found in the far more common phrase _zu Hause_ ‘at home’, as well in various other more or less fixed collocations (_zu Fuß_, _zufrieden_…).

Comment: I guess another example would be Tombach https://www.namenforschung.net/dfd/woerterbuch/liste/?tx_dfd_names%5Bname%5D=155153&tx_dfd_names%5BcurrentSelectedFacets%5D=&tx_dfd_names%5Bquery%5D=Tombach&tx_dfd_names%5Boffset%5D=&tx_dfd_names%5Baction%5D=show&tx_dfd_names%5Bcontroller%5D=Names&cHash=56d00a7d3bf5f5a521e4b5af126f5d5f